# Does the Poincare homology sphere smoothly embed in $\mathbb{C}P^2$?

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology

Does the Poincare homology sphere smoothly embed in $\mathbb{C}P^2$?

If so I guess one way to see this would be to have a handle decomposition for $\mathbb{C}P^2$ such that a subset of the 2 handles, together with all of the 1 handles is a surgery description of the Poincare homology sphere (after changing all of the dots on the 1-handles to zeros).  I can't seem such a description of $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

I do not know how one would go about proving that such an embedding does not exist.

Comment: Interesting question. I can show that every map $M \to \mathbb{CP}^2$ is nullhomotopic, but I don't see why that would prevent the existence of an embedding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Splitting $\Bbb{CP}^2$ into two pieces $X_1, X_2$ along the Poincare homology sphere  is such that $H_*(X_1) \oplus H_*(X_2) = H_*(\Bbb{CP}^2)$ for $* < 3$ (run Mayer-Vietoris). In particular we split the intersection form. Therefore one of the two pieces is a homology ball and the other is positive-definite. $\Sigma(2,3,5)$ can not bound the first piece, as it never bounds any negative definite manifold with diagonal intersection form by Donaldson's theorem: if it did, then capping off the $-E8$-manifold (a smooth manifold with intersection form $-E8$ and boundary $-\Sigma(2,3,5)$) gives a smooth closed oriented 4-manifold with negative definite, non-diagonalizable intersection form.

In a related but different direction, Proposition 3.4 of [this great paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06388.pdf) shows that the minimal $k$ such that $\Sigma(2,3,5)$ embeds in $\#^k S^2 \times S^2$ is $k = 8$.

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit confused - I guess it can not bound either a homology ball or a positive definite 4-manifold, right?  If it did we could cap off $-E8$ and get a contradiction as you said (I am assuming that $E8 + [1]$ is not diagonalizable?).  Does this then generalizes to show that you can not embed $\Sigma(2,3,5)$ into any number of connect sums of $\mathbb{C}P^2$?

Comment: @user There is an orientation issue here. -E8 + [1], which is what you would get by capping off the positive definite manifold you bound. Indefinite forms don't tell us anything exciting. This is the obstruction to making this argument work for higher connected sums: it could be that Sigma bounds a manifold with intersection form +1 on each side, but because of orientation conventions, if you want to consider those with boundary Sigma, one of those ends up being positive definite and the other negative. And you can cap E8 off with the positive one just fine.

Comment: But you can't cap it off with the negative one by Donaldson, right?  And therefore you can't embed in $\mathbb{C}P^2 \sharp \mathbb{C}P^2$? I guess that I am assuming that $-E8 + [-1]$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @user101010 Oh, of course. Good point. It seems counter-intuitive to me that I can never embed in a positive-definite manifold but let me think a bit to make sure I haven't done anything wrong.